# Is restarting a website with "docker-compose up" after a host server reboot a standard practice?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I created a Wordpress website with the `docker-compose.yml` below.
I started it with `docker-compose up -d`  (Note that the MySQL and Wordpress data are persisted in subdirectories of the local directory: `./mysql` and `./wp`).
Then let's say we reboot the host server.
**How would you restart these containers/this website?**

- Would you just redo `docker-compose up -d`?

  I tried, and it works indeed, but this actually **recreates**
  new containers! Fortunately, as it reuses the same data directories and as it [detects that `/var/www/html` is non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64271784/how-does-volumes-override-the-docker-images-original-files-with-docker-compos/64272044#64272044), a new Wordpress installation is not triggered, so "everything is ok", but still, isn't *recreating new containers* bad practice **since the website already exists**?
- **Is there a more "graceful" way to restart containers made with `docker-compose` after host server reboot, rather than "recreating" the containers?**

---

```
version: '2'
    services:
       db:
         image: mysql:5.7
         volumes: ['./mysql:/var/lib/mysql']
         restart: always
         environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcdef
           MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
           MYSQL_USER: wp
           MYSQL_PASSWORD: abcabc
       wordpress:
         depends_on: ['db']
         image: wordpress:latest
         volumes: ['./wp:/var/www/html']
         ports: ['8000:80']
         restart: always
         environment:
           WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
           WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp
           WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: abcabc
```

Comment: Creating new containers is absolutely 100% routine and normal.  You make many config changes by deleting the existing container and creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to start containers which are created by docker-compose.

After rebooting the machine:

1. Run:  `docker ps -a` to show all stopped-container, and you can start container manually, `docker start [container_name or container_id]`
2. Run: `docker-compose start [service]`.
   Starts existing containers for a service.

In your case:

```
docker-compose start db
docker-compose start wordpress
```

or just

```
docker-compose start
```

> Starting db ... done
> Starting wordpress ... done

Before rebooting, `docker-compose stop`.

Comment: I was speaking about detaching from terminal, but I see it's ok with just `docker-compose stop`, `docker-compose start`.

Comment: `docker-compose start` is always in "detached" mode.